# Android 2.3 and Adhoc

Tags: android

Android 2.3 is coming out soon. I was curious if anyone knew if android 2.3 will have support for adhoc networking without rooting or at least support it better with rooting? The list of stuff added for 2.3 just said bug fixes, i was wondering if anyone knew what bugs they were fixing or had a link to a list.

Thanks

Comment: A this isn't a real programming question and B which list?

Comment: This is a development question. It is directly related to programming certain applications that i am working on.

Comment: I was about to redirect you to the Android Enthusiasts ES site but apparently you've already posted that question there which is the right place for it not here.

Comment: Basically you might want to check the Git log on http://android.git.kernel.org/ - some of the changes of recent Android versions might be found here. Yet many of the new stuff that is going to be introduced in the next Android version is in some private Git repositories at Google so I suggest you just have to wait until they merged it into the public repository. Should be just a few days left. ;-)

Comment: Still awaiting an answer and still researching possible solutions... we may have something in the next month or an alternative approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android 2.3 is out. No ad hoc. Another crippled beta version of Android.

And NO. AD HOC IS !NOT! SUPPORTED IN 2.2, although most (if not all) hardware platforms support, which it works with root and some extra code.

Answer (score 1):

sorry anton, but a WiFi HOTSPOT is not neccessary and WiFi Ad-Hoc connection.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing has been announced regarding the next version of Android.

Comment: If you do a simple google search on android 2.3 you can see several announcements about version 2.3.

Answer (score 0):

AdHoc networking is already supported in Android 2.2.

Comment: I believe you are wrong, if you have proof of this please let me know. I am talking specifically about not having to root and working on all phones.

Comment: "Certain devices like the Nexus One can be turned into a portable Wi-Fi hotspot that can be shared with up to 8 devices." -http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.2-highlights.html, well I guess not all devices will support it, but all relatively new most likely will.